# The wrong language is shown in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

consider my code bellow -

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSString *weekDay = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
    NSLog(@"%@", weekDay);
    return  weekDay;
```

when i am running my app in xcode then it does work nicely and showing it in english .  But when i run it on  iphone it is showing in danish in few area. Even though after setting  iphone default language in english it shows then in danish also.  But when i change region in US then it shows in english.
Can you suggest me how i can fix this problem. Just i want to show it in english when language is set in english.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `NSDateFormatter` the local that is being used.

To get the systems current local use:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormat.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale]
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *weekDay = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"%@", weekDay);
return  weekDay;
```